# Python - A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a game in Pygame that requires a client-server part for the multiplayer.

First, I am checking if there are less than two connections. If this is the case, the client will be shown a screen that says 'waiting for connections'.

I have got the client to successfully send a '1' message to the server, which will respond with a '1' if the server is not full. Therefore, if the server does not respond with a 1, the server is full, and the client can continue.

However, I am getting this error mentioned in the title.

Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
from _thread import *
import time

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host=socket.gethostname()
ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)
port=8000

connections=[]

print('Your local ip address is',ip)

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(2)

def  threaded_client(connection):

    while True:
        data=connection.recv(2048) #anything we receive
        if not data:
            break

    connection.close()


def checkconnected(connections):
    noofconn=len(connections)



while True:

    print('Waiting for a connection...')
    connection,address=s.accept()
    print(address,'has connected to server hosted at port',address[1])
    connections.append(address)



    data=connection.recv(1024)

    received=[]
    counter=0

    for letter in data:
        received.append(data[counter])
        counter+=1

    received=(chr(received[0]))     

    if received=='1':#handling initial connections
        if len(connections)!=2:
            s.sendall(b'1')

    if not data:
        break


    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(connection,))


s.close()
```

The client code that calls it:

```
host=socket.gethostname()
            ip=socket.gethostbyname(host)
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            address=address
            port=8000

            if address==ip:
                ishost=True

            else:
                ishost=False

            try:
                s.connect((address,port))
                connectionwaitingmenu()
                connected=False

                while connected==False:
                    s.sendall(b'1')
                    data=s.recv(1024)
                    received=[]
                    counter=0

                    for letter in data:
                        received.append(data[counter])
                        counter+=1

                    received=(chr(received[0])) 

                    if received=='1':
                        connected=False
                    elif received!='1':
                        connected=True
                        classselection()
```

The error occurs on the s.sendall(b'1') line in the server code.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few other problems in your code, but the cause of the error in the title is that you're using the wrong socket to send and receive data on the server side.

When a server accepts a new client (`conn, addr = server.accept()`) this returns a *new socket*, which represents the channel through which you communicate with the client. All further communication with this client happens by reading and writing on `conn`. You should not be calling `recv()` or `sendall()` on `s`, which is the *server* socket.

The code should look something like this:

```
# Assuming server is a bound/listening socket
conn, addr = server.accept()

# Send to client
conn.sendall(b'hello client')

# Receive from client
response = conn.recv(1024)

# NO
server.send(b'I am not connected')
this_wont_work = server.recv(1024)
```